# mariaDB json_object/json_arrayagg

Tags: mysql, массивы, node.js, mariadb

Есть запрос, в котором вытаскиваю данные о игроке, у игрока есть 2 вещи и 1 противник в отдельных таблицах

```
pool.query(`SELECT json_object(
                            'game_id', G.id,
                            'game_mode', G.mode,
                            'game_submode', G.submode,
                            'game_maxplayers', G.maxplayers,
                            'game_createdAt', G.createdAt,
                            'game_game_round', G.game_round,
                            'player_nickname', C.nickname,
                            'player_avatar', C.avatar,
                            'player_vip', C.vip,
                            'player_domain', C.domain,
                            'player_id', A.player_id,
                            'player_race', A.race,
                            'player_class', A.class,
                            'player_level', A.level,
                            'player_cash', A.cash,
                            'player_points', A.points,
                            'player_battles', A.battles,
                            'player_battles_bosses', A.battles_bosses,
                            'player_status', A.player_status,
                            'player_position', B.player_position,
                            'player_action', B.player_action,
                            'player_made_action', B.made_action,
                            'player_action_name', B.action,
                            'player_dices', B.dices,
                            'player_time_action', B.time_action,
                            'items', json_arrayagg(
                                json_object(
                                    'item_type', E.type,
                                    'item_subtype', E.subtype,
                                    'item_name', E.name,
                                    'item_description', E.description,
                                    'item_image', E.image,
                                    'item_level', E.level,
                                    'item_price', E.price
                                )
                            ),
                            'enemies', json_arrayagg(
                                json_object(
                                    'enemy_type', H.type,
                                    'enemy_name', H.name
                                )
                            )
                        ) players

                    FROM games G
                    LEFT JOIN game_players A ON A.game_id = G.id 
                    LEFT JOIN game_events B ON B.player_id = A.player_id 
                    LEFT JOIN users C ON C.id = A.player_id 
                    LEFT JOIN game_items D ON D.player_id = A.player_id 
                    LEFT JOIN items E ON E.id = D.item_id 

                    LEFT JOIN game_enemies F ON F.player_id = A.player_id 
                    LEFT JOIN enemies H ON H.id = F.enemy_id 

                    WHERE G.gs_token = ? GROUP BY A.player_id
```

Получаю такой ответ

```
    RowDataPacket {
        players: '{
"game_id": 22, 
"game_mode": "0", 
"game_submode": "1", 
"game_maxplayers": "3", 
"game_createdAt": "2022-09-06 19:18:11", 
"game_game_round": 396, 
"player_nickname": "Moonbeam", 
"player_avatar": "/img/CuqTPZzRPIE4qKEu", 
"player_vip": 0, 
"player_domain": null, 
"player_id": 1, 
"player_race": "elf", 
"player_class": "warrior", 
"player_level": 11, 
"player_cash": 0, 
"player_points": 0, 
"player_battles": 0, 
"player_battles_bosses": 0, 
"player_status": 1, 
"player_position": 39, 
"player_action": 1, 
"player_made_action": 0, 
"player_action_name": "battle", 
"player_dices": "[6,4]", 
"player_time_action": "2022-09-26 18:44:40", 
"items": [
 {"item_type": "armor", 
  "item_subtype": "head", 
  "item_name": "Мотоциклетный шлем", 
  "item_description": "Описание", 
  "item_image": "/img/items/armor/head/helmet.svg", 
  "item_level": 3, 
  "item_price": 800
 },
 {"item_type": "armor", 
  "item_subtype": "body", 
  "item_name": "Жилет", 
  "item_description": "Описание", 
  "item_image": "", 
  "item_level": 6, 
  "item_price": 1800}], 
 "enemies": [
  {"enemy_type": "normal", 
   "enemy_name": "Npc1"
  },
  {"enemy_type": "normal", 
   "enemy_name": "Npc1"
  }]
}'
 }
```

В запросе есть 2 json_arrayagg - items и enemies
Если привязано 2 и более вещей, то дублируются enemies (Противники) приходит 2 раза Npc1 и тоже самое с вещами, если 2 противника и к примеру 1 вещь, то эта вещь дублируется, как их можно сделать "независимыми" друг от друга, к примеру если 1 вещь и 2 противника то вывести

```
"items": [
 {"item_type": "armor", 
  "item_subtype": "head", 
  "item_name": "Мотоциклетный шлем", 
  "item_description": "Описание", 
  "item_image": "/img/items/armor/head/helmet.svg", 
  "item_level": 3, 
  "item_price": 800
 }], 
 "enemies": [
  {"enemy_type": "normal", 
   "enemy_name": "Npc1"
  },
  {"enemy_type": "normal", 
   "enemy_name": "Npc2"
  }]
```

Comment: *Если привязано 2 и более вещей, то дублируются enemies (Противники) приходит 2 раза Npc1 и тоже самое с вещами, если 2 противника и к примеру 1 вещь, то эта вещь дублируется, как их можно сделать "независимыми" друг от друга* Вас удивляет, что JOIN двух таблиц по 2 записи каждая даёт 4 итоговые записи? нет? а что тут удивляетесь? Агрегируйте таблицы по отдельности в подзапросах, где никакого дублирования не будет, и только потом JOIN в основной запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо **Akina** за наводку), необходимые данные правильно приходят, правильно ли я реализовал и не скажется ли это на производительности из за таких вложенностей?

```
pool.query(`SELECT json_object(
        'game_id', G.id,
        'game_mode', G.mode,
        'game_submode', G.submode,
        'game_maxplayers', G.maxplayers,
        'game_createdAt', G.createdAt,
        'game_game_round', G.game_round,
        'player_nickname', C.nickname,
        'player_avatar', C.avatar,
        'player_vip', C.vip,
        'player_domain', C.domain,
        'player_id', A.player_id,
        'player_race', A.race,
        'player_class', A.class,
        'player_level', A.level,
        'player_cash', A.cash,
        'player_points', A.points,
        'player_battles', A.battles,
        'player_battles_bosses', A.battles_bosses,
        'player_status', A.player_status,
        'player_position', B.player_position,
        'player_action', B.player_action,
        'player_made_action', B.made_action,
        'player_action_name', B.action,
        'player_dices', B.dices,
        'player_time_action', B.time_action
    ) player,
    (SELECT json_object(
        'items_all', json_arrayagg(
            json_object(
                'item_type', items.type,
                'item_subtype', items.subtype,
                'item_name', items.name,
                'item_description', items.description,
                'item_image', items.image,
                'item_level', items.level,
                'item_price', items.price,
                'item_active', game_items.item_active,
                'item_slot', game_items.item_slot
            )
        )
    )
    FROM game_items LEFT JOIN items ON items.id = game_items.item_id WHERE game_items.player_id = A.player_id) items,
    (SELECT json_object(
        'enemies_all', json_arrayagg(
            json_object(
                'enemy_type', enemies.type,
                'enemy_name', enemies.name,
                'enemy_description', enemies.description,
                'enemy_image', enemies.image,
                'enemy_level', enemies.level,
                'enemy_undead', enemies.undead,
                'enemy_damage', enemies.damage,
                'enemy_buffs', enemies.buffs,
                'enemy_rewards', enemies.rewards
            )
        )
    )
    FROM game_enemies LEFT JOIN enemies ON enemies.id = game_enemies.enemy_id WHERE game_enemies.player_id = A.player_id) enemies
FROM games G
LEFT JOIN game_players A ON A.game_id = G.id 
LEFT JOIN game_events B ON B.player_id = A.player_id 
LEFT JOIN users C ON C.id = A.player_id 
WHERE G.gs_token = ? GROUP BY A.player_id`,[gs_token], (error,result) => {
```

Comment: а чем ваш ответ отличается от того, который вы уже дали пару часов назад? может быть, лучше было внести правки в предыдущий, а этот удалить?

Comment: А как удалить полностью ответ?